# What's the most efficient way to stream video from AWS CloudFront with a bearer token in Next.js?

Tags: amazon-web-services, video, next.js, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I'm using Next.js and `getServerSideProps` to fetch a video stream from AWS CloudFront, but the page is loading very slowly.

```
export const getServerSideProps = withPageAuthRequired({
  async getServerSideProps(context) {
    try {
      // ... fetch access token and meeting details ...

      const videoSrc = await fetch(`https://cloudfrontURLHere.cloudfront.net/${meeting.meeting_video}`, requestOptions);
      const buffer = await videoSrc.buffer();

      return {
        props: {
          video: buffer.toString('base64'),
        },
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return {
        props: {},
      };
    }
  },
  ssr: false,
});
```

This code works but it takes a long time to load the video, especially for larger files. Is there a more efficient way to fetch video streams from CloudFront in Next.js (with authorization included)?

Thanks.